# How to implement a gesture keyboard on Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, gesture

I am trying to make a gesture only android keyboard and am hitting a road block (or many).

I have read through the android documentation online about IMEs and have followed a couple tutorials successfully on how to make general QWERTY keyboards.

The problem I have is how to replace the QWERTY keyboard with just a View that can return x and y coordinates. I have created a demo app that does exactly what I want my gesture keyboard to do (activity and all), and I simply do not understand how to change the UI of an IME so that I can begin doing the same on an actual IME.

**My question:** how do I change the UI from a QWERTY keyboard to a simple View (or View child) that I can then get X and Y coordinates from?

My current attempt shows the X coordinate at he bottom left of the screen, but only if touching the screen along the horizontal path of the TextView. I am unsuccessful in my attempts to enlarge this TextView to receive more touch input. (I would include a screenshot but lack reputation)

Below I have my messy code where I edited a QWERTY Keyboard to have a simple UI of a TextView. It was a TextView that I previously used on my demo app to get the X and Y coordinates from, I realize this may not be the best implementation in the end. I am simply trying to wrap my head around how the IME UI works.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simplekeyboard">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service android:name="SimpleIME"
            android:label="@string/simple_ime"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
            >
            <meta-data android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**method.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <subtype
        android:label="@string/subtype_en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
</input-method>
```

**ikeyboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/xCoord"
    android:text="X:"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </TextView>
```

**SimpleIME.java**

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
        implements OnKeyboardActionListener{

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        tv = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ikeyboard, null);

        tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int action = event.getAction();

                switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getX()));
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
        return tv;
}
```

Comment: have you achieve gesture typing?